# Entity Framework 4.1 Insert, Update Delete ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a wizard where I am in updatemode. During this mode, I can actually insert, delete or update various records in the model. I am passing by reference to m CRUD methods. eg. MyMethod(ref Project project)

I was able to update by attaching my project to the context but when I also need to Delete during the same tranaction, update and delete do not do anything, How am I supposed to handle delete?
I do the following which does not work.

```
var FoundProjectUser = (from m in UserRoles where m.UserProfileId == member.UserProfileId select m);

                if (FoundProjectUser.Count() == 0)
                {

                    project.ProjectTeams.Remove(member);

                }
```

ANSWER FOUND:

I found the problem. The problem is that in edit mode, the project is not attached to the context. I need to delete from the DBContext and not the project. Like this.Context.ProjectTeams.Remove(member);

Answer (score 0):

.Remove will only flag the row for removal. You have to do entity.SaveChanges() to persist the changes.

Comment: Yes I did that. I found the problem. The problem is that in edit mode, the project is not attached to the context. I need to delete from the DBContext and not the project. Like this.Context.ProjectTeams.Remove(member);